# Ruby on Rails tutorial, wont load pages/home

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

After running:

```
rails generate controller Pages home contact
```

and adding the following to my Gemfile, and rerunning bundle install, i still get the following in the logs...

```
ActionView::Template::Error (Could not find a JavaScript runtime. See https://github.com/sstephenson/execjs for a list of available runtimes.
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.  thanks!

Comment: gem 'therubyracer'
gem 'execjs'

Answer (score 1):

Since I am running passenger, I seem to need to restart Apache after any bundle installs :)

Thanks!